# How can I create (or do I even need to create) an alias of a DNS MX record?

Tags: dns, mx

I am in the process of moving my DNS records from Network Solutions to the Amazon Route 53 service. While I know and understand a little about the basic kinds of records, I am stumped on how to create the record that will point to the MX record on Network Solutions (if I'm even saying that right).

On Network Solutions I have this:

```
Mail Servers (MX Records)  

Note: Mail Servers are listed in rank order

myapp.net 
Add Sub-Domain
MXMailServer(Preference)    TTL  
inbound.myapp.net.netsolmail.net.(10)   7200    Network Solutions E-mail
```

I have read that the payload for an MX record state that it must point to an existing A record in the DNS. Yet in the example above, that `inbound.myapp...` record only has the words "Network Solutions E-mail" next to it. Our email is hosted at Network Solutions.

I have already created the CNAME records that look like this:

```
mail.myapp.net  7200   mail.mycarparts.net.netsolmail.net.
smtp.myapp.net  7100   smtp.mycarparts.net.netsolmail.net.
```

Since I am only using Amazon as the DNS, do I even need to do anything with that MX record? I appreciate your help, I googled and researched this before I posted, this is my first post on webmasters although I've been on SO for a few years.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/348609/how-do-i-set-an-mx-record-in-route53-for-a-godaddy-domain) Server Fault question might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You created a `CNAME` alias which points to the domain name of the MX record, this won't do what you want. A mail server explicitly looks up MX records so you need to put the alias into the MX record, for my Google Apps account I have the following in my zone file:

```
mail.example.com.   300 IN  MX  5   alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
mail.example.com.   300 IN  MX  1   aspmx.l.google.com.
example.com.        300 IN  MX      aspmx.l.google.com.
```

Comment: I don't think I was clear about the CNAME records I set up, I have clarified them, please let me know if your answer still applies.

Comment: Unless they are marked as MX and have a priority set they will not be read by the mailserver. I can't check NetSol as I have everything pointed to Cloudflare.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice to create MX records is to create a name alias then point to that alias with MX record.

For example, you have a mail server with IP: `1.2.3.4` and need to receive email on domain `example.com`.

1. Create A record `mail.example.com` with IP address `1.2.3.4`
2. Create MX record that points to `mail.example.com`

Note: Never create MX records that point directly to the IP address.